# Cursor control in console display

Tags: c, console

`ANSI.SYS` is missing in windows 8.1; so how do I create cursor control in a console display?

I am currently using C; if it cannot be done in C, can it be done in C++?  `Config.sys` is supposed to have `DEVICE=ANSI.SYS`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to mix the ancient ancient *ancient* MS-DOS technologies with the modern Windows NT console. ANSI.SYS is missing because it's *looong* dead.

What you want to do instead is take advantage of the NT console. [Here's a starting point in the API documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) In particular, [there's a guide on handling mouse input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that you can use as a starting point.

You may find it easier to use a library like [Termbox](https://github.com/nsf/termbox) or [pdcurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/), depending on the type of program you want to write. There are even some text-based user interface (TUI) libraries, such as [Turbo Vision](http://tvision.sourceforge.net/), if you want to write that kind of program instead.